# How do prevent pip and easy_install from removing the temporary directories?

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I need to debug some failures to install packages using pip and it seems that once I get the error pip is removing all the temporary files, preventing me from looking inside and finding what happened.

The gist below contains the error that I get but I do want to find-out which config file is generating this error and all the files from tmp are removed by the time the script ends.

https://gist.github.com/ssbarnea/b373062dd45de92735c7482b2735c5fb

Answer (score 14):

From my experience with pip 19.0.3, it is sufficient to use the `--no-clean` option, which is available to both [`pip install`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-clean) and [`pip wheel`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_wheel/#cmdoption-no-clean).

It can also be specified in the respective sections of the [pip configuration file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file):

```
[install]
no-clean = true

[wheel]
no-clean = true
```